# How do you add a comment to .npmrc?

Tags: node.js, npm, .npmrc, npmrc

My `.npmrc` looks like this:

```
node-options=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

I want it to look like this:

```
COMMENT the following line is needed for node 18 or higher
node-options=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

How do you add a comment in `.npmrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lines in .npmrc files are interpreted as comments when they begin with a ; or # character.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc#comments